# Wordpress SEO Plugin (Yoast) and canonical tags

Tags: wordpress, seo, canonical-link

We have a WP blog and we are currently using the awesome SEO Plugin by Yoast. I am trying to figure out what is the action that I need to take on my theme, to get the canonical tags to appear. On the plugin's settings I have left the canonical setting to default. Doesn't this mean the plugin should add the canonical tag on the pages? What am I missing?

Thanks,
Iraklis

Comment: You want the canonical tags to appear on the page? Aren't they appearing in page source like rel=canonical?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. No, they don't. Is there anything in specific that I need to add to the template (header.php) file?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install a [Canonical link elements plugin for WordPress](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/canonical/).